# Generating pass_words with input mask

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, input-mask

I have such input masked word like `---`  and I want to replace all `-` with numbers`(0-9)`

Code:

```
def masker(input_mask,pattern):
 s = list()
 s = (itertools.product(pattern,repeat=1))

 for i in input_mask:
  if ( i=='-'): 
   for j in s :
    print (input_mask.replace('-',''.join(j)))


masker ('-a-' , '123')
```

but my output is:

```
1a1
2a2
3a3
1a1
2a2
3a3
```

And my main goal is this output:

```
1a1
1a2
1a3
2a1
....
....
3a3
```

Comment: ...and why do you want to do this?

Comment: its etc simbol  its nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code `j = '1'` in the first run. you then just replace all `-` with that...

---

my suggestion would be to use `str.format` as `mask` (i.e. replacing your `-` with `{}`). then you could do this:

```
from itertools import product

def masker(input_mask, pattern):
    mask = input_mask.replace('-', '{}')  # mask = '{}a{}'
    for values in product(pattern, repeat=2):
        print(mask.format(*values))

masker(input_mask='-a-', pattern='123')
```

also note the `repeat=2` in the `product`. to make it more generic you need to use `repeat=input_mask.count('-')`.